# Why is the size of a pointer less than the addressable size of virtual memory space?

Tags: pointers, memory-management, process, operating-system, virtual-memory

What I understood is that the addresses which we deal with in the user-space programs are virtual memory addresses, not actually physical memory addresses. Memory-Management-Unit will map those virtual addresses into actual physical addresses.

But on a 32-bit machine, I observed that size of a pointer is mostly 32-bits but whereas a process can actually occupy more than 4GB virtually i.e., virtual address space of a program is addressable by more than 32-bits ( For a program with 8GB of virtual address space, it's virtual memory is addressed by 33 bits). 
So I  can not use pointers (which are only 32-bits in size) in my program to access the memory locations after 4GB.

So why is the size of pointer only 32-bits and why not more than that on 32-bit machines? What decides the size of a pointer?

Comment: Please explain how you think process memory address space can be larger than physical memory space.

Comment: @duffymo imagine a pc with 4 gb of ram, and executing a 64 bit application (64 bit os of Course) using 8 gb: then you will use 64bit addresses (pointers), although you only have 4 gb of ram, but an abundance of virtual memory

Comment: @shiva: I think this is not a concrete programming question, where a sode example would help, so SO is the wrong place

Comment: You don't address virtual memory; the operating system has to swap those pages in and out of physical memory for you.  All the operating system can address is physical memory; that's what compilers deal with.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561217(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Physical address bus width and pointer size are not related. Take for example the old [80286 processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80286) which had 24 bit wide address bus, but pointers typically was still 16 bits (on old DOS-based systems). [The MC 68000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68000) also had a 24-bit address bus, but pointers were typically 32 bits on systems using it. There is no relationship between physical address-bus width and the size of the pointers used on a system.

Answer (score 1):

Your program will most of the time run on virtual memory (unless you are writing an OS yourself). That is, the amount of memory you can address at the same time is always restricted by the size of virtual memory. Technically, the address size is tied to the underlying hardware's address bus size because HW (i.e., the MMU that actually translates these addresses to physical memory addresses) uses these sizes.

Nevertheless, there are options for your machine to use more physical memory than 4 GiB on 32 bit. On x86 this was called [Physical Address Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension). With PAE your computer can have more than 4 GiB of memory, but your single program can still only access 4 GiB of this at the same time (due to the 32bit address size restriction).